# How can I set 3 color to the same chartjs bar?

Tags: javascript, graphics, chart.js

my ideia is simple: I need a a chartjs and instead only one color I need to draw different colors to the same bar like:

[image: example different color]

Comment: Can you show what you have done?

Comment: Dude I will create a codepen to make it available here but actually I don't have nothing just a html with the chartjs imported. Actually I want to know if it's possible because I'm trying to get it in the documentation but no success...

Comment: Well, what is your problem? Do you want your elements in your chart to have different colors? For eg, in a bar graph, do you want each bar to be colored differently?

Comment: Not exactly... this way it's kinda ok and I can do it. But I meant, One bar with 3 colors as the showed in the image above.

Comment: But those bars with different colors represent different data/ ranges of data. It just so happens that the data is together which is why it looks that way. If your data is such, I'm sure you can have a different color for each. If your bar, which represent a particular value, and has different colors, wouldn't that more likely convey different information? Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can apply three colors to the same "bar" (which is a relative term here). But I do know you have the ability to create stacked charts like in this example here:

https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/bar/stacked.html

The key is to pass the stacked property as true when setting your chart options. Example:

```
...
options: {
    title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Chart.js Bar Chart - Stacked'
    },
    tooltips: {
        mode: 'index',
        intersect: false
    },
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            // MAGIC HERE
            stacked: true,
        }],
        yAxes: [{
            // AND HERE
            stacked: true
        }]
    }
}
```

I hope this can help you.